# Open selected text in an iOS app?

Tags: ios, applications, sharing

I just got an iPod Touch 5G (iOS 8.2) and I would like to open text in an installed apps, e.g.; TextCrafter. Is that possible? Images can be opened in a number of apps but how to do it for text?

Comment: Meaning, select some text -> open in TextCrafter? Or open a text document in TextCrafter?

Comment: I mean ->select some text -> open in TextCrafter - is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Text is handled by default with copy/paste. While it would be possible to create an app that allows text to be sent to TextCrafter (or similar), and a new document to be automatically created from that text, it is not default in iOS.

As a result, the only option is to copy the text (which is available system wide) and paste it into TextCrafter.